# SQLite/python: 'str' object is not callable error

Tags: python, sql, pycharm

I'm new to python and I've got an error that i tried to solve by myself for couple of hours with no result. (I use Pycharm & SQLite).Here's my code:

```
Id = cur.execute("select id from abonnement where libelle=%s and prix=%s and estPackGar=%s ;" (abonnement.libelle, abonnement.prix, abonnement.estPackGar))
```

And this is what I get for that line:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I do not have a clue about what is causing that. Any idea please?

Comment: Is this all of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `%`, so the formatting doesn't get applied as you would like. Instead you need:

```
Id = cur.execute("select id from abonnement where libelle=%s and prix=%s and estPackGar=%s ;" % (abonnement.libelle, abonnement.prix, abonnement.estPackGar))
```

As for why you get the error you get:
Essentially your error message results from having parenthesis directly after the string, a simplified example would be

```
"abc %s"(variable)
```

In which case python tries to call `"abc %s"` as though it were a function which fails because it's actually a string. This is why you get the "str is not callable" error. If however you use the string formatting correctly then you get the desired results:

```
"abc %s"%(variable)
```

I'd suggest using `.format` instead however, see this PEP: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/ and this question for more details about that: [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format)

Comment: @user3836861, glad this helped. I know the first time I ran into this error I was stumped because it seemingly had nothing to do with the code I was using.